# how to calculate mean distance of points in point cloud

Tags: 3d, computer-vision, point-cloud-library

I am trying to find normals of a point cloud with the help of PointCloudLibrary following is the code which I am using

```
        pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> ne;

        ne.setInputCloud (test1.cloud);

        pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree (new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ> ());

        ne.setSearchMethod (tree);

        ne.setKSearch (150);

        ne.setRadiusSearch (1.5);

        ne.compute (*Normalcloud);
```

I am using both methods KDsearch and Spherical Searching method but I have to manually decide or switch between both of them also have to manually enter the searching and/or number of neighbouring points.

**to avoid all that hassle I am thinking of using the mean point distance of point cloud to do all this stuff
something like this**

```
ne.setKSearch (0.8*Avg_point_Distance);

ne.setRadiusSearch (1.5*Avg_point_Distance);
```

**but I don't know how to get the mean distance for the whole point cloud?**

NOTE: if someone can edit the question in more understandable manner I won't mind that :)

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: @Dexter "I am thinking of using the mean point distance of point cloud to do all this stuff......." that part....Edited the post.

Comment: @Dexter it is solved now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through the PCL documentation and found Kd Search method, from that I just calculated the nearest neighbouring point and accumulated all the distances and divided it with number of points present in point cloud.

code snippet for the method is as follows:

```
    totalcount = inputCloud->width * inputCloud->height ;

    EuclidianDistance = new float [totalcount];

    kdtree.setInputCloud (inputCloud);

    int K = 2; //first will be the distance with point it self and second will the nearest point that's why "2"

    std::vector<int> pointIdxNKNSearch(K);
    std::vector<float> pointNKNSquaredDistance(K);

    for (int i = 0; i < totalcount; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "\nK nearest neighbor search at (" << inputCloud->points[i].x 
            << " " << inputCloud->points[i].y 
            << " " << inputCloud->points[i].z
            << ") with K=" << K << std::endl;

        if ( kdtree.nearestKSearch (inputCloud->points[i], K, pointIdxNKNSearch, pointNKNSquaredDistance) > 0 )
            {
                for (size_t j = 0; j < pointIdxNKNSearch.size (); ++j)
                {
                   //saving all the distance in Vector
                    EuclidianDistance[i] =  pointNKNSquaredDistance[j];

                }
            }
        }

    for(int i = 0; i < totalcount; i++)
    {
        //accumulating all distances
        totalDistance = totalDistance + EuclidianDistance[i];
    }

    //calculating the mean distance
    meanDistance = totalDistance/totalcount;

    //freeing the allocated memory      
    delete  [] EuclidianDistance;
```